# Excel Macro to 'Save As' in a set drive location as a .xlsm

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

I am trying to write a macro to save an excel file in a defined location, using a value in a cell as the title in the format .xlsm, it appears to work but does not actually save the file? i am not sure what i have done wrong? here is the macro:

```
Sub Savefileas()
ThisFile = Range("B4").Value
Dim varResult As Variant

varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
"Macro Enabled Workbook" & "(*.xlsm), *xlsm", Title:=Range("B4").Value &".xlsm", _
InitialFileName:="C:\Work\" & ThisFile & ".xlsm")

End Sub
```

Thanks in adavce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. Error catching has also been added.

```
Sub Savefileas()
    Dim ThisFile As String
    Dim varResult As Variant
    ThisFile = Range("B4").Value
    varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
    "Macro Enabled Workbook" & "(*.xlsm), *xlsm", Title:=ThisFile & ".xlsm", InitialFileName:="C:\My Documents\" & ThisFile & ".xlsm")
    With ActiveWorkbook
        On Error GoTo message
        .SaveAs varResult & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
        Exit Sub
        message:
        MsgBox "There is an error"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This has saved the file in the correct format, however using the previous macro i had the save as dialog box appear and this would give the user the ability to select another folder within the file structure. The idea is the spreadsheet is used for a variety of different projects once the user presses save they can select the correct project folder before finalizing the save. I hope i have made that clear

Comment: @Maxe1984 I've updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It doesnt seem to be grabbing the name from cell B4 only using the current work sheet name?? Also this is saving to last current folder, is there a way of specifying a starting location??

Comment: @Maxe1984 I have added both cell B4 as file name functionality and default directory functionality. To change the default directory, change the "C:\My Documents\" string for InitialFileName.